# PyroCMS Nested Navigation

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have started to use PyroCMS but I am unsure how to use the Nested Navigation,  Where do I find this with the admin area,

I am using Version 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was caused by some servers give a 406 Unacceptable error on any file that had "cookie" in the name.

The current fix can be located [HERE](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/commit/6cef90ff62702d8a51b03924651e50576d43971c)

Answer (score 1):

@jess McKenZie:
on admin panel

goto design -> Navigation -> Add Navigation Link -> now in target choose the parent page that for submenu.

this will help you